# Microsoft Graph API notifications to a lab server is failing due to SSL/TLS error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Trying to subscribe for callRecord resource on Graph API:

```
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://XXXXXXXXX",
  "resource": "communications/callRecords",
  "expirationDateTime": "2021-03-11T18:23:45.9356913Z",
  "clientState": "secretClientState"
}
```

Our client has a self signed certificate and when we try to POST the above to Azure, we get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-03-10T18:51:16",
            "request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "client-request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
        }
```

I believe this is related to our self-signed certificate on the receiver side but I am not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any instructions to make Azure trust a third party client?

Comment: Yes this error is not related to Microsoft Graph, rather it's pointing back to the certificates that you use. Just to isolate the issue above, try the Graph API call in Graph explorer and you will see it brings the value for you without any issue. It can be coming from the any of the SDK/library that you're using in your app or lab/vm's that you're using.

Comment: Is it possible to import my self-signed certificate to Azure under my account so that the notifications works?

Comment: Just to test the subscription, I tried to point it to https://www.google.com. This time it did not complain about the certificate. Instead it complained about google not responding with 200 OK. So I suppose I just need to find a way to get Azure accept my self-signed cert. I hope there is no limitations for this :)